# jQuery - Iframe validation - cannot get values

Tags: jquery, validation, iframe

[See demo here.](http://wip.redaxscript.com/home/editor-test)

The editor is under development. Now we check if it has
an value - this works well with all form fields that have the
class .required... but it does not work with the iframe.

the iframe has a div with id #content.

```
$('form .meet').focus(function() {
    $('iframe').each(function() {
    ** if($(this).contents().find('#content').val() == '') { **
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    }
    })
});
```

That means it should add the class .warning if the iframe is empty.
But it always does, so what am i doing wrong?

Does it not work, because the JS does not see the text i currently typed in? ^^

Regards
Henry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, per se, but #content is the `<body>` tag of your iframe, and I'm not sure what happens when you call `.val()` on the `<body>` element. Try substituting `.val()` with `.text()` and you should get the results you want.

```
$('iframe').each(function() {
    if($(this).contents().find('#content').text() == '') {
        $(this).addClass('warning');
    }
});
```

I verified that this works using Firebug, but let me know if it works on the actual page.